# Swift 5 URLRequest authorization header: reserved, how to set?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, authentication, http-headers

In the [documentation for Swift's URLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest/2011447-setvalue) in Foundation, it says that the standard method of setting header values for a URLRequest shouldn't be used for reserved HTTP headers.

Following the link to [the list of reserved HTTP headers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest#1776617) a little bit deeper in the docs, it says that it may ignore attempts to set those headers.

But it also says that `Authorization` is a reserved HTTP header.

This can't be right, can it?  A large percentage of the APIs in the universe require you to pass authentication tokens in a header of the form `Authorization: Bearer {token}`

So if Swift doesn't let you set the `Authorization` header, how does one access one of those APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation as you all mentioned, I've ended up for now to the following:

```
class ApiManager: NSObject {

    var credential: URLCredential?
    
    func token(withCredential credential: URLCredential?) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(K.API)/token") else {
            print("error URL: \(K.API)/token")
            return
        }

        self.credential = credential
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            self.credential = nil
            
            if error != nil {
                print("URLSession error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let safeHttpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("HTTPURLResponse error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            if safeHttpResponse.statusCode == 200,
               let safeData = data,
               let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("safeData: \(dataString)")
            } else {
                print("error: \(safeHttpResponse.statusCode)")
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Here, `token` is a method as an example to authenticate a user.

I pass something like that from the UI to this method

```
URLCredential(user: usernameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text, persistence: .forSession)
```

Then the most important, is the `URLSessionTaskDelegate`

```
extension ApiManager: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    // From https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/68809
    // We should use session delegate as setting Authorization Header won't always work
    
    func urlSession(
        _ session: URLSession,
        didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        // This method is called mainly with HTTPS url
        
        let protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace
        let authMethod = protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
        
        guard authMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust, protectionSpace.host.contains(K.API.host) else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
            return
        }
        
        guard let safeServerTrust = protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            SecTrustEvaluateAsyncWithError(safeServerTrust, DispatchQueue.global()) { (trust, result, error) in
                if result {
                    completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))
                } else {
                    print("Trust failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(
        _ session: URLSession,
        task: URLSessionTask,
        didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        // This method is called for authentication
        
        let protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace
        let authMethod = protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
        
        switch (authMethod, protectionSpace.host) {
            case (NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic, K.API.host):
                self.basicAuth(didReceive: challenge, completionHandler: completionHandler)
            // we could add other authentication e.g Digest
            default:
                completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
    }
    
    private func basicAuth(
        didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        
        if challenge.previousFailureCount < 3 {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, self.credential)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
    }
    
}
```

And I call everything like this:

```
let apiManager = ApiManager()
let credential = URLCredential(user: email, password: password, persistence: .forSession)
apiManager.token(withCredential: credential)
```

I have to handle the response with a completionHandler for example but the request is authenticated and works

Answer (score 1):

Setting or adding a value directly like other suggestions doesn't work in my case. I managed to solve it by creating additional HTTP Headers `URLSessionConfiguration`. Here's the code:

```
var sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
var authValue: String? = "Bearer \(token!)"
sessionConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": authValue]
var session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self as? URLSessionDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                
            }
        }.resume()
```

Comment: token can expire. You can't then change it your way because once URLSession is instantiated, later URLSessionConfiguration updates will not make any effect and will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Implement authentication challenge to handle Basic authentication like:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    switch challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod {
    case NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic:
        performBasicAuthentication(challenge: challenge, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    default:
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
}

func performBasicAuthentication(challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    let credential = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence: .forSession)
    completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
}
```

Here is the reference [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge)

Comment: Does that require the backend to support challenges?  I don't understand how this is supposed to work: if the API is looking for a specific header and doesn't see it, why would it send a challenge to the caller as opposed to just shooting back a 403 or something?

Comment: What if the authorization is not Basic auth? I want to implement token based authorization but I cannot set header with either request.setValue or URLSession.configuration additional headers for 'Authorization' field.

Comment: @PaulGowder did you resolve this? It doesn't seem that you can set an Auth header at all, even with the delegate methods of URLSession...

Comment: @MilesAlden no---I just switched to a different auto method for the API in question. Other folks elsewhere just recommended dropping down to lower-level networking in objective-c to do it.

Comment: @PaulGowder Nice, can you share what objc api you ended up with?